# How do I stretch an EditText to entire phone's width and leave a space for 1 button?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I am trying to stretch the EditText (on ActionBar) to "almost" entire screen's width.It should first leave space for a button to the right then the rest is EditText's pace. I can put about 300dp which could make it seem nice on my phone but it's not a preferable solution.

My code: 
action_menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_item_edit_text"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Add"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
```

action_item_edit_text

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/editInput"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:hint="Write something"
android:padding="6dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316540/how-to-make-layout-with-view-fill-the-remaining-space . IMO the proper solution is layout_weight. The view that should take fixed space gets a weight of 0, the view that should fill remaining space gets a weight of 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Something like that. I haven't tested this I just wrote it blindly, but the concept is sound.

Comment: action_menu only contain items so I am not very sure I should add a LinearLayout to it. It contains add button on the right and search field on left (which is in another XML file). I am trying to stretch the search "item" to entire ActionBar.

Comment: For menu items you can set layouts by using the android:actionLayout="@layout/my_layout" attribute

Comment: I've already did that. However, I am not very sure but I think an item can only link to 1 object. What I wanted was the 1st item (after leaving space for 2nd item on the right) would stretch all the way to the left. I solved the problem by adding collapseActionView to the first item. Upon clicking, it will open the EditText and stretch all the way left.