# How to make Android view width = (parent width - some constant)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a layout and I'm trying to have a view fill all the remaining space, EXCEPT some 50dp width image at the end. When I set the first view's width to `match_parent`, it occupies the whole view, and whatever I set to the image's width, it's placed outside the screen bounds. Here is what's happening:

[image]

But I want it like this: (achieved by setting the first view's width to a constant just to demo, which I definitely don't want as it should fill a dynamic amount of width)

[image]

Here is my current layout:

[image]

The problem is at the `LinearLayout (vertical)` which is just below the avatar view in the hierarchy. It occupies the correct space, but it's children are not acting the way I want.

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Comment: how did you design ur layout? you could use wifghts? post the layouts

Comment: What type of layout did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on this example. Main idea is to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for the view which has to take all available space. In mine case it is `TextView` in you case it can be another layout or anything else.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ....
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ....
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

More information can be found here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316540/how-to-make-layout-with-view-fill-the-remaining-space).

Comment: it worked! setting the textview's layout_weight to 1  did exactly what I needed. thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Make the layout using RelativeLayout and set center TextView element property to_rightof ImageView on the right side. Whatever be the size of the image, the textview wil auto adjust its width.