# Keep text in TextView with drawableLeft centered

Tags: android, textview

In my app I have a header bar which consists of a single textview with fill_parent as width, which have a specific background color and some centered text. Now I want to add a drawable on the left side of the header bar, so I set the drawableLeft and sure enough the text and image is displayed. However the problem here is that the text is no longer properly centered, e.g., when the drawable is added the text is shifted a bit to the right as shown in the screenshots here:

[image: without drawable]
[image: with drawable]

Is there anyway I can center the text properly and have the drawable positioned as it is above without using an additional layout item (such as a LinearLayout)?

Comment: Is it possible to make drawable also in center??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Though fragile, you can avoid the use of a wrapper Layout by setting a ***negative*** padding on the drawable:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
    android:drawablePadding="-20sp"
    android:text="blah blah blah" />
```

You'll have to adjust the padding to the width of the drawable, but you're left with just a single TextView instead of an extra LinearLayout or etc.

Comment: I don't think android:drawablePadding="-20sp" is correct, you should use android:gravity="center" instead!

Comment: You should do it java code by getting exact width of drawable you set.
gravity center will not work

Comment: Setting the drawable padding like this could have different behaviors on different APIs. It is also not safe to use it like this.

Comment: @cwhsu setting `android:gravity="center"` will have different effect if `RelativeLayout` is parent.

Comment: this answer is not correct,if the width of the text view is match parent,then drawable is getting shown at the start of the TextView.

Comment: If you have dynamic button size and what not this will unfortunately not be your silver bullet. So either do a custom view or wrap it inside a view group - which is super annoying...

Answer (score 15):

You can set the parent of the TextView as a RelativeLayout whose width is match_parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_location_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_location_text_view"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:text="Edit Location" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is what the result looks like.]

Answer (score 6):

I've faced a similar problem. Solved it by using single `TextView` with  `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `layout_gravity="center"` parameters:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:text="some text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: if  width is wrap_content, then whats the point of center? Tricky part is to center when width is set to match_parent or some other value. Would be good to point this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to center the text vertically with the image. Or it can be centered inside the textView using `android:gravity="center"`.

```html
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
    android:text="Your text here" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be the accepted answer. @Jacob

Comment: It doesn't work if `TextView` is `match_parent` in width

Answer (score 4):

That work for me.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/trusted"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/trusted"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try flowing:

```
public class DrawableCenterTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                  int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // We want the icon and/or text grouped together and centered as a group.
        // We need to accommodate any existing padding
        final float buttonContentWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

        float textWidth = 0f;
        final Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
                textWidth = Math.max(textWidth, layout.getLineRight(i));
            }
        }

        // Compute left drawable width, if any
        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        Drawable drawableLeft = drawables[0];

        int drawableWidth = (drawableLeft != null) ? drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth() : 0;

        // We only count the drawable padding if there is both an icon and text
        int drawablePadding = ((textWidth > 0) && (drawableLeft != null)) ? getCompoundDrawablePadding() : 0;

        // Adjust contents to center
        float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;
        int translate = (int) ((buttonContentWidth - bodyWidth));
        if (translate != 0)
            setPadding(translate, 0, translate, 0);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're downvoted, this is a better solution than half of the upvoted answers here. However you should add a description of why this works.

Comment: this answer supports only the text + drawable being centered inside the full width of the textview, should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

use this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
     >
  
  <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rlheader"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:background="@color/HeaderColor"
      
        >
 
        <TextView
           
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:text="Header_Title"
            />
 
        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/ivSetting"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:src="@drawable/setting" />
 
        
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it look something like this snap of my demo project

[image: Header Image]

Comment: Thanks, is it not possible to do something similar in a linearlayout or would I need to use a relative layout somewhere?

Comment: ya u can use parent layout as linear it works for u but child layout is relative in which imageview and textview i have put remain as it is

Comment: Why this iOS style back button in an Android app?

Comment: @ChristopherPerry because of the requirment of client

Comment: IMO it's your job as an Android developer, providing a service for your client regarding the Android platform, to inform the client that this is an iOS and not an Android pattern. I would flat out refuse to implement this if they still insisted and find another client.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry yes you are right i am working as android developer in company as project manaager told me than i have to do that way if i will be in that position than i am sure i told same as your reply.Thanks for giving me suggestion

Answer (score 2):

```
> This line is important ->> android:gravity="start|center_vertical


 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginplus2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/like"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/marginplus1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_like"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:text="@string/comments"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/marginplus1"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_comment"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/share"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/marginplus1"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved it with small changes in Textview,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_red"
    android:text="your text goes here"
    />
```

Comment: This does not work, the drawable will go to the left part of the View. Only the text will be centered.

Comment: it does not work with width as match_parent. It will work with width as wrap_content.

Comment: This should not work. The Drawable will be left aligned.

Comment: Doesn't work at all. The drawable just go to the left side. and the text is centered only.

Answer (score 1):

drawable is part of the TextView, so the textview's height will be the drawable's height if your text's height is smaller than drawable's height.

You can set TextView's gravity attribute to center_vertical, so the text will be in the center.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use a transparent image with the same size on the opposite side of the textview.
In my example i copied my actual vector_image and changed the colors to be transparent.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/TextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_vector_caret_down_green"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vector_space_18"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/green"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions did not work for you?. Then try below answer

Sample screen shot of the design.
[image]

For the above image please find the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/my_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_tv"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list"
                android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                android:text="Filter"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bb"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_tv"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:text="Sort"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.9dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_card"
        android:background="@color/gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not working for me, it fails if TextView width is match parent I did it using FrameLayout.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_circle_check_white"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

no test too much, another way

```
    class CenterDrawableToggleButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : AppCompatToggleButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

        private val centerMatrix = Matrix()

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
            canvas?.save()?:return
            centerMatrix.reset()
            centerMatrix.postTranslate(width / 2F - (getDrawWidth() / 2), 0F)
            canvas.concat(centerMatrix)
            super.onDraw(canvas)
            canvas.restore()
        }

        private fun getDrawWidth(): Float {
            return paint.measureText(text.toString()) + compoundPaddingRight + compoundPaddingLeft
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your TextView inside a LinearLayout. Then set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to your LinearLayout..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/your_drawable"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/ic_text_color"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:text="Your Text.." />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can set your header like this

```
<RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/head" >

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/cat"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:onClick="onClick"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/btn_back_" />


         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center" >

           <TextView
 android:id="@+id/TvTitle"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text=""
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:textColor="#000000" 

 android:textSize="20sp"/>
             </RelativeLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>
```

Just Give Hieght of Textview,image source as per your need

Comment: I realize there are multiple ways of doing this including your above answer, however I do wish to try and limit the amount of elements in the layout so I'm looking for a solution that only uses one textview, or knowledge about whether that is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/distance"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your textview instead of wrapping with another layout

```
android:gravity="center|start"
```

Answer (score -1):

simple as this.. try it..

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:text="something something" />
```

Comment: The gravity has no effect because you set the width to wrap_content.

Comment: Si se establece  android:layout_width="match_parent" , si funciona

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to use ConstraintLayout, to make the textview at the center of the layout and the width warp_content(don't use 0dp now)
so that the drawable will follow the text.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/you_drawable"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the DrawableLeft and use a container FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         android:src="@drawable/image" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That's not an answer, that's an ugly workaround :)). P.S. As you've stated don't "answer questions for points"

Comment: @farid I provided this answer because drawableLeft is untrustworthy. Just make sure the text won't overlap the image if it's too long. Set the left and right margins correctly

Answer (score -18):

The simplest way to obtain that is:

```
<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/head" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/cat"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:onClick="onClick"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:src="@drawable/btn_back_d" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Where

- ImageView has the alignParentLeft setted true and
- TextView has the centerHorizontal setted true

Comment: Thanks, is it not possible to do something similar in a linearlayout or would I need to use a relative layout somewhere?

Comment: Why you want use linearlayout? Relative Layout is the more flexible solution and it doesn't take any much load than LinearLayout. If you want read more about efficence differences between the two solutions you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout

Comment: well my overall design is much more suited for a linear layout I think so I would have to do <linearlayout><relativelayout>header</relativelayout><otheritems></linearlayout>, so if I could avoid using that extra linearlayout it would be great. Of course if that's not possible its ok as well I guess.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is the only solution that worked for me, so I don't really get the downvotes. Drawable left sucks, this works. However, it CAN be simplified using FrameLayout and `layout_gravity`.