# How to set textview in center of G+ sign in button in Android

Tags: android, gravity, google-signin

I am having G+ signinbutton in my code and its working fine for login.
I set it using below code in my xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            />
```

What I have now is as below
[image]

Now I want to set TextView to center of button. but, SignInButton doesn't seem to have `android:gravity` how can I set my TextView to center?

Comment: Instead of using this button can't u just create a custom one?

Comment: why i need to create whole custom button when google is providing with one\

Comment: I just need to have my textview adjusted, thats all

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261692/keep-text-in-textview-with-drawableleft-centered --- also, wouldn't a compound drawable to the trick?

Comment: you can set android:layout_gravity="center".

Comment: @GarimaMathur : to what? i guess you know how android:layout_gravity works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Karan - use below `code`, it's working for me.

```
    SignInButton signInButton = ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in));


    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do i need to write this code? in on connect i guess

Comment: @karanMer - use this code in your `Activity` or `Fragment` `class`.

Comment: then it is generating a NPE

Comment: did you initialize your `SignInButton` ?

Comment: @KaranMer - i'm talking about `G+ button`.

Comment: @KaranMer - no i didn't .

Comment: i am adding your code to oncreate just after `SignInButton signInButton = ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in));
`

Comment: @GauravVachhani Thanks, I was breaking my head over it for a while :)

Comment: It might suit better to use `break` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/small_margin">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sign_google"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:padding="@dimen/text_padding">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/img"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:src="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/sign_in"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```