# Bad layout performance due to view measuring?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I've ran into a performance problem, which I think is caused by measuring of my views. 
My layout is built programmatically, so I cannot show the xml of my layout. But here are some views which might contribute to the problem:

- A ScrollView for wrapping all the content (width: MATCH_PARENT, height: MATCH_PARENT)
- A LinearLayout containing all the differnt content parts (width: MATCH_PARENT, height: MATCH_PARENT, a child of the previous view)
- Two [LinearListViews](https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView) (LinearLayout) which are populated asynchronously (width: MATCH_PARENT, height: WRAP_CONTENT, children of the previous view)

The problem only seems to occur when I populate the LinearListView; adding views seems to trigger View.measure being called many times:

[image: Method profiling result]

Why is the View.measured called this many times? The LinearLayout having MATH_PARENT for its size means it doesn't have to measure it again when a child is added, right?

I'm not really sure how to prevent this from happening, or how to debug the problem. I've tried to set the visibility of the LinearListView to GONE untill all the items are added, but this didn't make a difference.

I hope I provided enough information for someone to point me in the right direction.

**Edit #1 (07/01):**

Here's some parts of the base class of the Adapters used for the LinearListViews:

```
public abstract class DataProviderAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter
{
    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        T item = getItem(position);

        Log.d(TAG, "getView(): Position: " + position + ", ConvertView: "
                + (convertView == null ? "null" : convertView) + ", TotalCount: " + getCount());

        if (row == null) {
            row = buildRow(position);
            markRowAsLoading(row);
        }

        if (item == null) {

            if (convertView != null) {
                markRowAsLoading(row);
            }

            int skip;
            if (itemsRequestParams != null) {
                int pageSize = itemsRequestParams.getTake();

                // determine how many items to skip
                skip = position - (position % pageSize);
            }
            else {
                skip = 0;
            }

            // if the page isn't already being fetched
            if (!pagesReceiving.contains(skip)) {
                pagesReceiving.add(skip);
                AsyncTaskUtil.executeMultiThreaded(new ReceiveItemsTask(), skip);
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + " - PrepareRow: " + getItemId(position)
                    + ", Pos: " + position);
            prepareRow(row, item, position);
        }
        return row;
    }

    protected void processDataResult(int skip, DataResult<T> result)
    {
        if (result instanceof GroupedDataResult<?>) {
            GroupedDataResult<T> groupedResult = (GroupedDataResult<T>)result;
            totalItemCount = groupedResult.getTotalGroupCount() + groupedResult.getTotalItemCount();
        }
        else {
            totalItemCount = result.getTotalItemCount();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.getItems().size(); i++) {
            itemList.put(skip + i, result.getItems().get(i));
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "processDataResult(" + skip + ")");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    static protected class CellHolder
    {
        public ProgressBar ProgressSpinner;
        public List<android.widget.ImageView> Images;
        public List<TextView> Labels;
        private final HashMap<String, Object> _extras = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public void putExtra(String key, Object value)
        {
            _extras.put(key, value);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> T getExtra(String key)
        {
            return _extras.containsKey(key) ? (T)_extras.get(key) : null;
        }
    }

    ...

    private class ReceiveItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, DataResult<T>>
    {
        private int skip;

        @Override
        protected DataResult<T> doInBackground(Integer... params)
        {
            skip = params[0];
            DataResult<T> items = getItems(skip);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground(" + skip + ")");
            return items;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DataResult<T> result)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "onPostExecute("
                            + (result == null ? "null" : result.getItems().size() + "/"
                                    + result.getTotalItemCount()) + ")");
            if (result == null) {
                return;
            }
            processDataResult(skip, result);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute end");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit #2 (07/01):**

I subclassed RelativeLayout and overridden onMeasure so I could log which views were being measured, and in which order.
These are the results:

```
07-01 15:37:37.434: V/DefaultLayout(8172): DefaultLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.434: V/DefaultLayout(8172): TabView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.434: V/DefaultLayout(8172): ItemDetailsContainerView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.438: V/DefaultLayout(8172): HeaderView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.438: V/DefaultLayout(8172): ItemDetailsInfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.438: V/DefaultLayout(8172): ItemReviewTableView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.438: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.438: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.442: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.446: V/DefaultLayout(8172): ItemReviewTableView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.446: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.446: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.446: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.446: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.450: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.450: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.450: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.450: V/DefaultLayout(8172): InfoFieldsLayout.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.450: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RelatedItemsTableView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.454: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.458: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.462: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.466: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.470: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.474: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.478: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.478: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.482: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.482: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.486: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.486: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.490: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.490: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.494: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.494: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.498: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RelatedItemsTableView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.498: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.498: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.502: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.502: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.506: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.506: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.510: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.510: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.514: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.514: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.518: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.518: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.522: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.522: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.526: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
07-01 15:37:37.526: V/DefaultLayout(8172): RatingView.onMeasure
...
```

This list goes on for a while. But what seems weird to me, is that it starts with measuring the top view (DefaultLayout.onMeasure), and then also measures ALL the children (so all the views). It does this multiple times!

What could be causing onMeasure to be called on the top view?

**Edit #3 (07/02):**

Could it be that `notifyDataSetChanged()` triggers the measuring of the top view?

**Edit #4 (07/03):**

Yes, it does seem like `notifyDataSetChanged()` triggers the top-level view to be measured (I was able to reproduce this in a new test project). And since the way my adapter works, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called multiple times.

What is the reason all views are measured when i call `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: You might want to provide some code showing how you populate the LinearListView. You're not going to get much better than guesswork without it. It does seem to be using a *lot* of time to measure. What's the `RelativeLayout`, though(item 19 on your profile list)?

Comment: @Geobits I've added some code of the adapter used for the LinearListViews.
It might not look as a lot of time, but that's because I'm not using the default Android emulator. With the default emulator the window freezes for about 30 seconds (depending on how many items are added to the LinearListViews).
I'll try to find out more about the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Do you use `layout_weight` for the `LinearListView`? And another obvious question, why not a `ListView` instead of that custom `LinearLayout` which is supposed to replicate a `ListView`?

Comment: I'm not using layout_weight anywhere. And I'm not using a ListView because I'm already within a ScrollView, so it needs to be an inline list without scrolling.

Comment: How many child views are we talking about? I've run into serious slowdown with > 50 or so rows in a single `LinearLayout`. Also, you may want to strip out most of the data, and focus on what happens when you add *one* row. Your logs might make more sense that way.

Comment: Each row has around 15 views, and both `LinearListView` have a maximum of 5 rows. So that's a maximum of 15 x 5 x 2 + the views in the `ScrollView` itself; so that's around 200 views being measured many times.

Comment: At ~200 views and a minimum 4-5 level deep layout the performance problem is normal I would say. Is the `ScrollView` the root of your layout? At maximum 5 rows are the LinearListView showing all of their rows(which would defeat the entire purpose of an adapter based widget)? If you answer yes to the questions above I'm almost sure you can replace the current unoptimized layout with a single ListView. Also, you didn't say if you tested(and if you tested it how did it behave) on a lower specs phone.

Comment: The `ScrollView` isn't the root of the layout, but it is pretty much near the root. The `LinearListView`'s are indeed showing all their rows. The thing is that the adapter used, is also used in a different place by a `ListView`, so it's just the ease of being able to reuse the same adapter. I did test it on a lower spec phone, here it takes up to 40 seconds before the app becomes responsive.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice. At least try to drop the `LinearlistView` and build the row manually(I didn't look at the source code for those widgets so this may provide a performance boost). You didn't posted the row layout file maybe you could further optimize that layout. Reusing that adapter would be nice but I guess you would want for the app to actually work before doing code optimizations:)

Comment: I do think I can improve the performance by removing redundant views, but I think there's a bigger problem in my case. After the activity is created, the `measure` of the root view is called 6 times (deeper views even more). I don't see why it needs to measure that many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say where the relative layout comes in, is this a wrapper around the list?

Relative layout always does two measure passes, according to Romain Guy, so this might cause some of the slowdown. Do you even have nested relative layouts by any chance? Apparently this could have exponential time complexity.

See this answer for reference (and a link to the Google io video where he actually says that):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496262/1281144

Comment: Life saver! 
I did have nested relative layouts. After replacing them with frame layouts, the performance went up 10+ time. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that strikes me straight away in your description is your LinearLayout which is the immediate (and only) child of your ScrollView is set to have a height of MATCH_PARENT - this is wrong - it should have a height of WRAP_CONTENT. The child of a ScrollView cannot be the same height as the ScrollView itself - otherwise it can not scroll.

Aside from  that, looking in the code for LinearListView I see this:

```
private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        setupChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        setupChildren();
    }

};
```

So whenever the underlying dataset changes setupChildren() gets called which removes all views and redraws them.

In your processDataResult() method you do this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < result.getItems().size(); i++) {
        itemList.put(skip + i, result.getItems().get(i));
    }
```

So the list is redrawing (on the UI thread of course) after adding each item.

I would modify the library myself to remove the call to setupChildren() in onChanged() like so:

```
private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        //setupChildren(); do nothing here
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        setupChildren();
    }

};
```

I presume onInvalidated() will get called when you call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed wrong. Changing this didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: Removing `setupChildren();` prevented the lists from being populated at all. `onChanged()` was only called twice, so this wasn't the problem :(