# In Android, what Layout is faster 1. FrameLayouts inside LinearLayout or 2. One big RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-recyclerview

I am considering two different layout arrangements for a view (which will be a row in a RecyclerView). They are different, but they will both work, either as

1. One container vertical LinearLayout containing rows of FrameLayouts e.g. LinearLayout -> FrameLayouts -> Content
2. One big RelativeLayout that contains all other views (no FrameLayouts but all TextViews, Buttons and such) e.g. RelativeLayout -> Content

Now I was wondering: which one would be more preferable in terms of Layout performance?

It was my understanding that a RelativeLayout has to be measured twice and thus is pretty slow, while a FrameLayout is fast and a LinearLayout is ok in terms of layout performance. In one case I would only have one container that is slow (RelativeLayout -> Content) in the other I would have two containers that are quicker (LinearLayout -> FrameLayouts -> Content).

Comment: Interesting question - why don't you try both, and let us know?

Comment: **2**. The less the Layout/View count is, the better.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we6poP0kw6E&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=7

Comment: @DerGolem So you are saying I should probably go with the RelativeLayout?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Haha yes, but we are on a tight schedule right now. Once I have more free time I could do that for sure. In the meantime.. why don't you try it for now and let me know? Just kidding, I guess in the end I could just measure, but I would be surprised if no one had done this before.

Comment: Yes, I'd go for that one.

Comment: @Doge If you're tight for time, then just go with one of them, and move on to more important things. It's unlikely that it's actually going to make a noticeable difference. Slowness due to nesting usually isn't a problem until it gets much deeper than 2 levels. If it's a problem later, you can come back and optimize.

Comment: `LinearLayout` is faster than `RelativeLayout` because relativeLayout needs to set position of all components every time it's loaded and `FrameLayout` is faster than the `LinearLayout` because frameLayout is simplest layout among all. So I'd say **FrameLayout** is fastest.

Comment: @Apurva Thank you, but you seem to misunderstand. The choice is either 1 RelativeLayout which arranges the content OR 1 LinearLayout, containing about 5 FrameLayouts as rows and each of those FrameLayouts contains parts of the content. So its not either 1 RelativeLayout, 1 LinearLayout or 1 FrameLayout, the choice is between 1 RelativeLayout OR a combination of FrameLayouts and a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 8):

Short Answer (TLDR):

If you really know what you're doing, RelativeLayouts can be faster.
If you don't, they can be much slower.

Long Answer:

Nesting layouts manually such as a FrameLayout within a LinearLayout versus using relative positioning in a RelativeLayout can have pros and cons either way.

The cost is in calculating the dynamic sizes such as "wrap_content" which must expand based on their children's needs or constrain due to parent's requirements.  This causes a factorial calculation problem which increases with depth.

Manual positioning by using nested views increases levels.  The shallower the level, the better but still work.  So literally the amount of work is the factorial of your level depth as described above.
For example:
A is nested under Root.
B is nested under A.
C is nested under B.
A affects Root's width.
B affects A which affects Root.
C affects B which affects A which affects Root.

Relative positioning by having one view position itself relative to another is the same as nested views in terms of dynamic sizing calculations since each relationship must be calculated with consideration of the other.
For example:

A is left of Root.
B is left of A.
C is left of B.
While A,B,C all live under Root, the dynamic measurement occurs like so:
A affects Root's width.
B affects A which affects Root.
C affects B which affects A which affects Root.

In other words, you have the same factorial calculation occurring.

So the only real difference is that RelativeLayouts give you finer control over relative positions at the cost of more complex XML.

On the flip side, with careful use of @dimens that are calculated ahead of time based on device attributes, the dynamic calculations can be avoided and when used properly, RelativeLayouts can be much more performant than any other layout when needing complex positioning.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the context, there's no easy way to answer this question. There are [existing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4069077/1900071) with similar discussions already, and it is thought that performance gain is negligible.

`RecyclerView` allows you to reuse existing ViewHolders. A limited amount of ViewHolders ("RecyclerView pool") is created once, with different view type count in mind.

Assuming you do not spoil `ViewHolder` pattern, by, e.g.  inflating views each time in bind method, you are unlikely to feel the difference between RelativeLayout and LinearLayout root layouts.

However, if you use some sort of objects with dynamic size properties (e.g. `ImageView` with height set to wrap_content and you load different bitmaps into it), it is likely that your layout will be invalidated and calculated again on each call to `onBindViewHolder()`.

So my assumption is, reasonable usage of RelativeLayout won't bring you into any performance trouble.

Comment: ViewHolder has nothing to do with it as it only caches views and saves you the time to find views.  Time to find views is arguably the same for any view as it has less to do with the view type and more to do with the nesting or number of levels of indirection between the root view and the view you're looking for.  The real cost is calculating dynamic dimensions of views which happens factorially as nested depth increases.