# Which layout is better in terms of Performance in Android? RelativeLayout or Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

There are quite a few articles on the performance of Relative and Linear Layouts. Using Nested LinearLayout would cost in traversals because of the bigger view hierarchy. I don't know why it is not preferable to use RelativeLayout every time as I heard it in Google I/O 2013 but the reason was not given in that video

Is there anyone who can help us understand the in-depth concepts (Performance, resource costs etc.) behind these layouts.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no single universal answer to this question. As with many things in programming, the real answer is "it depends on circumstances".

Comment: @cricket_007 Dude i have read it already but it is not a complete answer. :(

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please elaborate those possibilities.

Comment: What more are you looking for? The true answer here is "it depends on what you want to display". Like if you want a grid, use a grid or table layout, a list of data goes in a ListView, etc

Comment: I think at the latest Google I/O's the ConstraintLayout is claimed to be superior to even RelativeLayout

Comment: @cricket_007 Let me see that one

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: I would add: those two are not entirely interchangeable; RelativeLayout can do things that LinearLayout can not, so if you need them then there is no comparison. If you only need to arrange things linearly, then use LinearLayout since it is conceptually simpler.  Otherwise, you need to create your specific use of them in each and measure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RelativeLayout is measured twice, so LinearLayout has better performance when used right.

Comment: RelativeLayout is measured twice. What does it mean?

Comment: `LinearLayouts` also go through two measurement passes in some cases (e.g., using weights).

Comment: True, relativelayout can be used in most cases as far as I know it. Unless you are creating complex layouts. This explains the measuring a little:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607737/in-android-what-layout-is-faster-1-framelayouts-inside-linearlayout-or-2-one