# What is the disadvantages of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I was ready some articles about performance optimization for android layouts. Most of them recommended using `RelativeLayout`s over other layouts because this might help you avoid Nested Layouts, that consume memory.

Personally, I believe that every thing has its Advantages and Disadvantages. But I could not figure out the disadvantages of the `RelativeLayout`s over the different types of layouts.

**What is the disadvantages of RelativeLayouts?**

**When I should avoid using RelativeLayouts?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there's no disadvantage of using RelativeLayout! Rather I'd say it's better among all layouts, you can position your components at the desired position.

Comment: I believe there is, at least this link saying that **Relative layouts include an additional pass for measuring, but it is recommended** ... http://blog.echolocker.com/performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, RelativeLayout is too much time consuming if you have to reorganize your components. That is the biggest downside.

For this reason, I would say RelativeLayout are really good as top level layout, and bottom level layout. But the mid-level layouts, are better served using the taylored (Linear, Table...) layout.

For example, when creating a form, the very top layout of my Activity or Fragment will be a RelativeLayout, but my form will be created as one big vertical LinearLayout. And inside this Linear, each line will be a RelativeLayout in which I will have a Text View and an Edit Text.

This way I can very easily sort the fields of my form and (I think) I keep my layout memory friendly by not overusing nested LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Relative Layout is the most used layout in most cases and from my experience, no disadvantage using this layout.Like I said before pick whichever is the best for the job, and worry about performance later.

update :

I copied comment from [Is a RelativeLayout more expensive than a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout)

> In a talk at Google I/O 2013 (Writing Custom Views for Android),
>   Romain Guy clarified the misunderstanding that caused everyone to
>   start using RelativeLayouts for everything. A RelativeLayout always
>   has to do two measure passes. Overall it is negligible as long as your
>   view hierarchy is simple. But if your hierarchy is complex, doing an
>   extra measure pass could potentially be fairly costly. Also if you
>   nest RelativeLayouts, you get an exponential measurement algorithm.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA&t=1m41s
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA&t=38m04s
>
> https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325615129

Comment: Thanks for those general info. But I know all that. I'm asking about the mechanism of `RelativeLayout` and the cases that using it is not recommended.

Comment: Relative Layout is the most used layout in most cases and from my experience, no disadvantage using this layout.Like I said before pick whichever is the best for the job, and worry about performance later.

if you really-really worried about the disadvantage, performance, & etc.. you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout

Comment: This is a useful link. Modify your answer and add it into it with some description for people.