# PercentRelativeLayout is more Performant?

Tags: android, performance, android-support-library, android-percentrelativelayout

I always use LinearLayout and RelativeLayouts, and i was reading about the "new" [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). I have a few questions:

- Should i always start using this one or only in cases of nested weights with linearlayout?
- Is this more performant than the others?

Any other information about PercentRelativeLayout it will be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/309059f029f498bf0bf2c431c9f3617915271d7f/percent/src/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.java), a PercentRelativeLayout is basically a minor extension of a RelativeLayout. This means you need to make the same considerations as when you choose between a RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.

- RelativeLayout needs 2 measure passes -> avoid using it as the root of a deep view hierarchy or nesting multiple RelativeLayouts (more info in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout) post)
- Layout weights in LinearLayout also require 2 measure passes -> try to replace these constructs as much as possible with one Relative/GridLayout (more info in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives) post)

Finally it is worth noting that:

- Don't optimise unless you have a problem
- Try to keep your hierarchies as flat as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
PercentRelativeLayout
```

is just a extension of `RelativeLayout` so i think:

1) u should use it in case of nested weights with linearlayout as they are bad for performance

2)No,but depends on your useCase. For ex:-it has less performance than `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` but more than `LinearLayout` with nested weight

Also u can refer this post from android developer:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score -1):

Try PercentRelativeLayout and PercentFrameLayout of Percent Support Library

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/08/try-percentrelativelayout-and.html

here you can find best comparison for both layouts.