# Two buttons overlap in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

First and foremost, I am new to Android Development, so this question might sound a little juvenile, but I am not able to get an answer to this. I have an app in which I need to display two different buttons side-by-side. I have specified the tags necessary to this and they run in one emulator but not in the other. Below is my code for button design:

file_name.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>

   //some code here

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:paddingTop="15dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />
      <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="45dp"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:paddingTop="15dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with my tags, because as far as my knowledge goes, layout_toRightOF will place button2 after button1's layout completes. Also I have statically provided marginLeft for both.

Both the buttons appear in one emulator(google play services installed) and not in other(google play services not installed). Is it because of google play services not installed? Or some fault in the design of my buttons?

Any kind of help would be helpful.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Question, why not just use a LinearLayout?

Comment: I tried using LinerLayout but the problem still persists.

Comment: You are using alignParentLeft/Start on both, but you don't actually want to align both to the left/start do you? Also, use `toRightOf="@id/button1"` (get rid of the + in the id)

Comment: What is the expected output? What are you seeing? If you are not seeing either it could the be parent layout.

Comment: thank you guys for the suggestion, I will give it a try.

Comment: @zgc7009 - thank you for the suggestion, removing alignLeft and alignStart solved the problem. Would you mind including this suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it as acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That was a typo from my end. I have changed the code now. I changed the names from my app over here to button1 and button2 to simplify.

Comment: No, I had a typo on stackoverflow, in my code I am using the same id

Comment: No. I had changed the name of buttons here on stackoverflow to button1 and button2 in order to simplify the names. In my app, the id is google_maps and I am using android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/google_maps" Like it is shown in my question right now.

Comment: what are you suggesting?

Comment: 1st use the code and tell me whether its working or not.

I am suggesting to remove these lines only

         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

Comment: You are most welcome. 
Please up vote the answer for other users help

Comment: i would love to, but I do not have enough reputations to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use relative layout ?? 
If you need two button side by side you can just use one linear horizontal. So something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:weightSum="10"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Relative layouts provides you more flexibility but it has to do two measure passes ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496262/3354265)). So, it's better if you go with linear layout.

Comment: *Better* really depending upon the situation

Comment: That's true @cyroxis . I just wrote in context with requirement to this question :)

Comment: @user3354265 - i tried using LinearLayout the same way but it did not help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?? Can you provide some picture/ diag?
Because the above code should work if you just want 2 buttons side by side like this     [BUTTON 1] [BUTTON 2]

Comment: LinearLayout is working now, I had to make a few changes in my button declaration, viz removing align_ParentLeft and align_ParentStart which solved the problem. Thank You for the suggestion though. I appreciate your time and effort.