# RelativeLayout vs nested Linear Layout performance

Tags: android, android-layout

For a long time I heard that RelativeLayouts are slow. In a couple of talks I recall hearing that this type of layout calls onMeasure twice and that for some reason is a drag to performance.

However, I am taking a performance course at udacity and I watched the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=303&v=gK9tdeqqigE

Here, the instructor used the Hierarchy viewer tool to compare the rendering cost of the same viewgroup using a relative layout and nested linear layouts.

In the video, the relativelayout is the clear winner, which contradicts everything that I have heard until now about the issue.

Could you please help me to understand in which circumstances each approach is better?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Is a RelativeLayout more expensive than a LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout)

Comment: In the android dev docs, they also had an article that is related to this topic -> https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a very broad question and there's no single, simple answer. LinearLayout is generally simpler (and therefore faster) than RelativeLayout, but LinearLayout has a problematic case if you nest multiple of them inside each other, *with weights on the same axis*. Then it has to iteratively divide up the space and this takes lots of layout passes (it's so bad there's a lint warning against this).

Even when you avoid that case, then with nested LinearLayouts you will still have a deeper view hierarchy compared to using RelativeLayout, so while LinearLayout is faster, that balances out at some point.

So it becomes the same thing as with all things performance: the only way to be absolutely sure is to measure and see what happens.