# Is there any determining factor for selecting a specific layout in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm familiar with almost all the basic layouts in Android & understand when they are to be used. I know that a `RelativeLayout` is to be used when elements in the UI are to positioned relative to each other, that a `LinearLayout` is to be used when UI elements are to be displayed vertically or horizontally. So I was wondering if the ease of development was the only factor that determined what layout should be selected or if there was any performance factor involved. I mean I can lay out two `ImageViews` vertically in Android using both `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, so why use a particular layout then?

Comment: I think you covered the basics, and are simplifying the problem a little

Comment: If you can do something with LinearLayout or with RelativeLayout, use Linear-  it lays out faster because it doesn't have to calculate rules.  Relative layout becomes necessary when you have overlapping views, or complex layouts-  there are things that you can do with relative that can't be done with linear.

Answer (score 0):

There are some performance gains for avoiding certain things, such as nesting `RelativeLayout` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/android-is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout)). Also, [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) recommend making layouts shallow and wide, which can facilitated with `RelativeLayout`, again for performance reasons.

However, often thinking about such things will be premature optimization for simple layouts, and you should use whatever makes the most sense for the situation.