# Textview setText left and right

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml, android-relativelayout

This is my Textview

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vagon_class_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="II Class 19 EUR"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
```

As you can see text is II class 19 Eur.Is it a possible to write my text like this when i have only one Textview/ II class in left side and 19 Eur in right side. 
I try to get this solution because i have textSelector xml and when i have two textview's not working correct.Only first textview's selector workin.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#4d4d4d" />
<item android:color="#4d4d4d"/>
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selected_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_selected_departure"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vagon_class_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="II Class"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/testselectorcolor"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="12dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="25 EUR"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"

            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/testselectorcolor"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"


            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: I want to receive like this result]

Comment: It is not possible, you will need two TextViews

Comment: Create a layout and put two TextView in it

Comment: I updated my question please see it  @AlexTa

Comment: I updated my question please see it @ Phạm Lam

Answer (score 0):

Now you can have action on both - background and text color state change

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/vagon_class_name"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="16dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="II Class"
  android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
  android:textSize="16sp" />

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingRight="16dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:text="25 EUR"
  android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Text selector: drawable/text_color_selector.xml

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
  <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Background selector: drawable/bg_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/selector_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:drawable="@color/selector_focussed" android:state_focused="true" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: I tried it also,but not working..can you continue discus in chat ? @mpals

Comment: @Baggio Sorry I misread your question, do you want to change text color or you want to add background selector ??

Comment: Both. change selector background color and also change text color in both  Textviews @mpals

Comment: @Baggio Updated answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  ...>

  <TextView
     android:width = "match_parent"
     android:weight ="1" />

  <TextView
     android:width = "match_parent"
     android:weight ="1"
     android:gravity = "end|right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May be its good to read [RelativeLayout vs LinearLayout with weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for left and right alignment

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alreadymem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Already a Member?"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/textLoginAccount"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```