# How to know how much time take for loading layout in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to check which layout is loading fast with the same design like Relative Layout, Linear Layout or Constraint Layout but I can't get any tool or any idea about that so please help me out for my query.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: may helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069037/is-a-relativelayout-more-expensive-than-a-linearlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this trick may help you.

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: " + (time2 - time1));
```

My results for empty parent layout:

`ConstraintLayout`: 74ms

`RelativeLayout`: 54ms

`LinearLayout`: 55ms

`FrameLayout`: 57ms

Have tested in Huawei Nexus 6P. Maybe these results will be different, when these layouts draw multiply views, but `RelativeLayout` is leading for empty layouts.

Answer (score 0):

A single layout can be made in many different ways. It all depends on the requirement, but still, there are some ways through which we can find the performance of layout. There are some inbuilt tools in our Android Studio itself, like **sys trace, layout inspector**. There are few ways in our developers' option in our device, that option is **GPU.** You can also find out which method is taking how much time.

For more clarity, I suggest you go through these topics.