# How to align FAB between two EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I want to place the Floating Action button in between two editTexts inside a CardView like this:
[cardwithedittext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St5Sc.jpg)

I tried the following but it isn't working.

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
                android:layout_width="204dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter origin address" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFindPath"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:onClick="fabClick"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_coordinator_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|end" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter destination address" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: use relative layout or constraint layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter origin address" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter destination address" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFindPath"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="fabClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_coordinator_layout" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have changed the padding and margin, set it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fabHolder"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fabHolder"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputHolder"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/inputHolder">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should avoid using Relative Layout wherever possible, let alone nested Relative Layouts. See this for explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496262/8039601

Comment: Yes, but it is easy for beginners.

Comment: But in this case, a nested linear layout is simpler than a nested relative layout. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this using linear layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Your hint" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Your hint" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFindPath"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="fabClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_coordinator_layout" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```